# Connecting to a Windows machine from a separate, Ubuntu machine on my home network

Tags: networking

I have Windows 10 on one machine and Ubuntu 20.04 on another, completely separate machine. They both connect to the internet through my home network. My Windows machine has no problem at all seeing the Ubuntu machine and can access that machine through shared folders. This is all great; but I would like it to work the other way too.

When I open the Files utility on the Activities bar and then click on Other Locations I can see a pretty purple icon which is labelled Windows Network. When I click on that, all I see is an empty folder.

If I ping the Windows machine from the terminal all I get is Destination Host Unreachable.

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong?

Update: I don't know how to configure the windows firewall, but I did turn it off in Windows Defender. I also checked the IP addresses and those are also ok.

Comment: Do you configured a firewall in Windows ?

Comment: Ubuntu 20?   So this is a Ubuntu Core 20 installation; as 20 is a different product to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Please be precise with details as they matter.

Comment: Did you set up a shared folder in Windows? Are you using the correct IP address?

Comment: By any chance, is your Ubuntu machine connected via a wired network to your router and Windows machine via a wireless one (or the other way around)?

Comment: Have you made your Windows system a server: made it share some directory?